# Best way to organize a android project into a subversion repository

Tags: android, svn, version-control, repository

I'm in the process to learn Subversion, and so far I've learned one thing or two, and I've just created a Google Code account and a svn repository to store a simple project, my problem is how to organize my svn repository. Imagine I've just created a android project named "Hello World" and his test project named "Hello World Test", should a import both the projects into my repository's trunk? It makes sense to put my test project into the repository trunk too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In Local File Ssytem:

The best approach Google recommended is, from [Official Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjects):

> You can create a test project anywhere in your file system, but the best approach is to add the test project so that its root directory tests/ is at the same level as the src/ directory of the main application's project. This helps you find the tests associated with an application. For example, if your application project's root directory is MyProject, then you should use the following directory structure:
>
> ```
> MyProject/ 
>   AndroidManifest.xml
>   res/
>     ... (resources for main application)
>   src/
>     ... (source code for main application) ...
>   tests/
>     AndroidManifest.xml
>     res/
>       ... (resources for tests)
>     src/
>       ... (source code for tests)
> ```

#### In SVN Repository:

The whole point of subversion is for teamwork, the best approach is no doubt using trunk/tags/branches structure:

> ```
> https://svn/my-repo/
>   MyProject/
>     branches/
>       1.1.1-fork/
>         AndroidManifest.xml
>         res/
>         src/
>         tests/
>     tags/
>       version-1.0.0/
>         AndroidManifest.xml
>         res/
>         src/
>         tests/
>       version-1.1.0/
>     trunck/
>       AndroidManifest.xml
>       res/
>       src/
>       tests/
>         AndroidManifest.xml
>         res/
>         src/
> ```

How do we use it usually:

- when developing, always checkout/commit from trunk/.
- before each release, tag the ready-to-release code (from trunk) under tags/.
- if work with others at the same time (major change), branck a copy of code (from trunk) under branches/ and start working on your branch, once done, merge it back to trunk for next release.

From my own experience, the most efficient and reasonable structure (used for both local file system and version control system) for a group of projects is [Maven's Multi-Module Project](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation), check out [this samples in GitHub](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/libraryprojects).

Answer (score 1):

It's completely up to you. Personally if I have a test project as well they would both come under the same folder.

```
svn
  /HelloWorld
      /HelloWorld
      /HelloWorldTest
```

that way if you have branches or tags you can keep them in the subfolder as well.

At the end of the day it's just a folder structure like like your home folder or 'my documents' and you can organise (or soothe your OCD) however you want

Answer (score 1):

As for my experience working with Java projects and svn i think that is more usefull to have the business classes and the test classes inside the same project because both are part of the same whole project.